# How to disable popup when clicking on select when viewing from a phone?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
let tar = e.target;

  if(tar.closest('select')){
    let current = tar.options[tar.options.selectedIndex];
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.marginTop = '5px'
    div.style.marginLeft = '40px'
 
    if(current.hasAttribute('selected')){
      current.removeAttribute('selected');
      div.innerHTML = 'remove'
      tar.after(div);
    } else {
      current.setAttribute('selected', '');
      div.innerHTML = 'add'
      tar.after(div);
    }

  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

When click on `<select>` from the phone, the event of the click works, for obvious reasons, not as desired. Based on this, I would like the `<select>` to work on mobile devices as well as on the desktop.

Comment: Sorry, but define "for obvious reasons".  They're not obvious to me, in fact none of the question is obvious to me.  When you say "not as desired", what are you expecting to happen?  What is it doing that is shouldn't be?  You need to edit the question and make it a lot, lot clearer

Comment: In addition to what @freefaller said, I do not believe what you want can be accomplished using the typical HTML select element. How the browser chooses to implement the select element you cannot control. Another option would be to write your own select-like element using other tags.

Comment: You can "detect" whether the device is a mobile device in a few different ways. The most bang for you buck might be this, but I haven't tried it: https://coderwall.com/p/i817wa/one-line-function-to-detect-mobile-devices-with-javascript  |  There's more verbose code available here: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/  |  Or if you want quick and dirty, you could just get the screen's height and width, and if either is less than 500px or so, treat it as a mobile device.   |  What you'll choose to do with the information once you get it depends on what you want mobile users to see.

Comment: @freefaller "for obvious reasons" I meant that when you click on the select from the phone, a modal window pops up with a choice of options that is not handled by the click event

Comment: @trx - I would be amazed if there is any difference in the event handling.  However, I think the problem is your code... you're doing `tar.closest("select");` and then immediately `tar.options`.  I believe your `tar` is the `<option>` element, so `.options` doesn't exist.